# How to concatenate EC2 hostnames in config file in Ansible playbook?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I try to write ansible playbook to setup MongoDB shard cluster in Amazon EC2.
I create three EC2 instances using ec2 ansible module ( http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html )

```
- name: Create EC2 instances for MongoConfigs
  ec2:
    key_name: mongo
    ..............
    wait: yes
  register: ec2_config
```

Ok, ec2_config variable contain created instances list.

Then on all mongos instances I have to start mongos with configDB param: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#sharding.configDB
( You must specify either 1 or 3 configuration servers, in a comma separated list )

For example, I have template:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "/logs/mongodb.log"
  logAppend: true

sharding:
  configDB: {{ configDBHosts }}
```

How I have to set **configDBHosts** value like this:

ip-10-0-103-87.us-west-2.compute.internal:27019,ip-10-0-103-88.us-west-2.compute.internal:27019,ip-10-0-103-89.us-west-2.compute.internal:27019

?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a for something similar:

```
host_list: "{% for host in play_hosts %} {{ host }}:{{ port }} {% endfor %}"
```

Comment: The comma is missing. To solve the problem with the comma in the last (or first) element you can use `{%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif -%}`.

Comment: See @udondan's answer below.  For comma separated this is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure in which format the `ec2_config` is. Given it is a simple list you can create the desired format like this:

```
{{ ec2_config | join(":%d, " | format(port)) }}:{{ port }}
```

The port and the comma will be used as glue in join. Since the port at the last element will be missing then, you output the port again at the end of the string.